# Creating objects from a string

Tags: java

I know if I were in `PHP` I would be able to create an object as following:

```
// class Name
$var = "Name";
$my_name = new $var("John", "Doe");
```

Now, I wanted to adopt similar approach in `Java`. I have a file which I need to parse and produce objects depending on the line read from the file. For example:

```
2235:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::8::addRate::9
2235:org.powertac.common.Tariff::8::new::8
2235:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::10::new::1::PRODUCTION
2236:org.powertac.common.Rate::11::new
2236:org.powertac.common.Rate::11::withValue::0.015
2236:org.powertac.common.Rate::11::setTariffId::10
2236:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::10::addRate::11
2236:org.powertac.common.Tariff::10::new::10
2247:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::12::init::DistributionUtilityService::0::model::-7651755067434358
2257:org.powertac.genco.Genco::13::new::nsp1a::true::true
2258:org.powertac.genco.Genco::13::new::nsp1a
2258:org.powertac.genco.Genco::15::new::nsp1b::true::true
```

then I should create an object of the type `Rate`, (`new`), with default values.
Therefore, parsing that line would yield me:
`"org.powertac.common.Rate"`(`String`) and I wanted to create a `org.powertac.common.Rate` object. How could I do it? I know it's a lazy evaluation ... how can I create something similar in `Java`?

Comment: You're looking for reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Java [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html) API:

```
String className = "org.powertac.common.Rate";
String ctorArg = "8";
Class<Rate> clazz = (Class<Rate>) Class.forName(className);
Constructor<Rate> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Rate rate = ctor.newInstance(ctorArg);
```

Then, if you want to [invoke a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) using Reflection:

```
String methodName = "setTariffId";
String methodArg = "1";
Method setTariffId = clazz.getMethod(methodName, String.class);
setTariffId.invoke(rate, methodArg);
```

Comment: @philippe: But don't you have the name in a variable after parsing the line?

Comment: I do ... but how could I create for example:
`Rate rate = (Rate) Class.forName("org.powertac.common.Rate").newInstance();`

Comment: Instead of `"org.powertac.common.Rate"` use the name of the variable which holds that value.

Comment: For example, `org.powertac.common.Tariff::8::new::8` has:
`org.powertac.common.Tariff` is the class name, 8 is the order it is being executed, and `8` is the argument to the constructor, how could I create a `Tariff` object with that argument?

Comment: @philippe: I've put up an example.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use some preexisting serialization / deserialization solution in Java, but here's something that would work for your String based approach:

```
Class<?> rateClass = class.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.powertac.common.Rate");
Constructor<?> constructor = rateClass.getConstructor(String.class);

Rate rate = (Rate)constructor.newInstance("Value")
```

So in this case:

```
2258:org.powertac.genco.Genco::15::new::nsp1b::true::true
```

you would do the following:

```
String className = "org.powertac.genco.Genco";
Object[] args = {"nsp1b", true, true};

Class<?> rateClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
Constructor<?> constructor = rateClass.getConstructor(String.class, boolean.class, boolean.class);

Object deseraliazed = constructor.newInstance(args);
```

You may want to store the type along with the constructor values.

Comment: Johncarl I've updated my question ... There is also the arguments for the constructor, which goes after the `new` keyword

Comment: Right, the constructor arguments are represented by the class type in the getConstructor() method, and the value in-order in the newInstance() method.